# How to know the Linux package name I need to install in order to get a missing C/C++ library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, header-files

When working on a C++ open source project, I've notice that the following header file

```cpp
#include <cpp/poppler-document.h>
#include <cpp/poppler-page.h>
#include <cpp/poppler-version.h>
```

is missing on my Ubuntu system. After delving on internet, I find out that I should install the following package

```bash
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-dev
```

to get the this library on my system. I wonder if it is possible to know beforehand the Linux package name I should install in order to obtain a missing library. It is nontrivial to guess that the library to be linked to the `poppler*.h` header files is within the `libpoppler-dev` package.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: *"I wonder if it is possible to know beforehand the Linux package name I should install in order to obtain a missing library"*  Since it's an open-source project, they should have mentioned this dependency in their documentation. If not, raise an issue there.

Comment: Note that the dev package contains files needed for development, such as the header file.  The runtime package would contain the library.

Comment: @kiner_shah "*Since it's an open-source project, they should have mentioned this dependency in their documentation.*" It is mentioned the dependency on poppler, indeed. But it is not said how to get this library installed. My question is how to know the Linux package name, not the library dependency name.

Comment: @RubemPacelli, I see.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use the web interface to find the package you're looking for by searching the contents of packages in https://packages.ubuntu.com as 237K has suggested in the comments. There are also command line tools to do this as well, namely `apt-file` (you might have to `apt-get` this if it's not installed already). On my system, it suggests `libpoppler-cpp-dev` for the header you're looking for.

```
user@host:~$ apt-file -x search 'cpp/poppler-document.h'
libpoppler-cpp-dev: /usr/include/poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h
```

There's even some regex options for this tool if you want to make more clever searches.